# Filter records from Redshift based on records from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am new to AWS. I am working on designing a solution for the below use case.

I have a copy of a relational database in S3, there are several files in a bucket, each file represents a table and the columns are pipe delimited. The total size of the files would be around 2 GB.
I also have several billions of records distributed across multiple tables in redshift.

I need to filter records from redshift(by joining several tables) based on the records available in S3 (by joining several files) and write it to a DB/S3.

Example - let's say S3 has Product file that has the product details and criteria file that has the criteria details, when criteria matches the product should be shown as a suggestion to the customer. Criteria and product table are linked using product id. Example, display ipad accessories (product) as a suggestion when the customer has already bought ipad (criteria)

Redshift has Customer table that has the list of customers and Product table that has the list of products that they bought. Both products and customers are linked using customerid.

For every product available in S3 based on the criteria, i need to find the list of customers to whom the product should be suggested based on the product that they have already bought.

Can someone please help with a high level idea of how to achieve this in AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into Redshift Spectrum which will allow you to define external tables that live in S3.  An external table will allow you to pull only those records from S3 that meet your criteria and then join this info to your customer tables.

This should work well for Spectrum as your S3 data isn't very large and you are paring it down by your criteria before the result is passed to Redshift proper.  Spectrum is most powerful when your S3 data is pared down with simple WHERE clauses and reduced by GROUP BY.  This keeps the network traffic for the results small when passed back to the RS cluster.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Sorry, if i was not clear. For every record (product + criteria) in S3, i need to be find the list of customers to whom the product should be suggested. So the S3 data is not pared down, the customer data in Redshift has to be filtered using the criteria available in S3 based on the product they have already bought.

Comment: Spectrum will still work in that case but may have some performance implications.  External tables in S3 can be referenced just like a normal table in Redshift.  Your S3 size isn't huge so the network transfer time may not be an issue for your use case.  It sounds like you are applying some ML groupings against the larger data set.  This is very doable in Redshift and the length of the query run time will likely out weigh the network time to pull 2GB from S3. If correct this is a process you likely run once in a while, not every other query.  You should be good.

Comment: If the external table access time is hit repeatedly and the network overhead is hight then the S3 data can be loaded into temp tables for the duration of the analysis so that they can be use many times over.

Comment: Can this query be scheduled/triggered to run automatically and store the results in S3? For example - when a new set of files arrive in S3, i need to automatically rerun the query based on the new feed in S3 and the newly available records in redshift ?

Comment: Yes but not from within Redshift (no triggers).  This isn't a big issue as you have the whole power of AWS to use.  You can schedule queries from the console (and a large number of other services) but I expect you really want to trigger based on S3 update.  The best way to do this is with Lambda functions.  S3 object update can trigger a Lambda which can issue all sorts of actions including SQL.  (Or on an EC2 but I like serverless.)  One thing to think about is when to trigger - first S3 object change?  Last? How do you know last? etc

Comment: Thank you, i will try this out..